# Elements in an extension of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Assume that $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a finite field of $p$ elements and that we have the following extension $\mathbb{F}_p \subset\mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is some infinite field (apparently of positive characteristic). Moreover, assume that we choose an arbitrary element $c \in \mathbb{F}$. If this element satisfies $c^p = c$, then does this imply that $c \in \mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: Do you mean $c^p=c$?

Comment: Yes I do! Isn't the same?

Comment: @user430191 Of course not, $3^2=9\neq 3$ but $3^2 \equiv 3 \mod 2$.

Comment: @Sahiba: In $\mathbf{F}_2$, $9=3$.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes. I was just trying to show that $c^p=c$ and $c^p \equiv c$ is not the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the polynomial $f(X)=X^p-X\in \mathbb{F}[X]$. Since $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, this polynomial has at most $p$ roots in $\mathbb{F}$.

On the other hand, every element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a root of $f$, so these $p$ elements must be precisely the roots of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}$. Hence if $c\in \mathbb{F}$ and $c^p=c$, then $c\in\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Nice answer! thank you a lot!